# python importlib, how to invalidate cache of dynamically loaded file

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.5, python-module

Given this code, how can I tell python to not use cached sources or reload?

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('test', '~/myfile.py')
test = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(test)

test.do_stuff()
```

when the content of myfile.py changes its not picked up, I'm assuming because it's cached. calling `importlib.invalidate_caches()` did not  help and `importlib.reload` results in an error saying test is not in sys.modules

Comment: importlib.invalidate_caches() does work. You don't show us how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `'~/myfile.py'` will not work.
You have to use relative path like this:
`'myfile.py'`
or absolute path like this:
`'/home/your_name/python_code/myfile.py'`